# Mustache.to_html method returing me empty String ("")?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, mustache

When I am using `Mustache.to_html` method it is returning me empty string `(“”)` . but when I am debugging code and moving ahead by using check points than I am getting my template,
Why I am getting such kind of behavior ?
My code is like that -

```
    var temp = $.get(/templates/mytemplate);
    var data = {
               name : "john",
   };
    var html = Mustache.to_html(temp,date);
```

I am getting `html` as `""` but by using breakpoing I am getting correct html. Why ?

Comment: Looks like this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call, also you seem to be missing quotes...

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = $.get(/templates/mytemplate);
    var data = {
               name : "john",
   };
var html = Mustache.to_html(temp,data);
```

There is spelling mistake like date instead of data..